# Remove hours, minutes and seconds from Carbon date

Tags: php, date, datetime, php-carbon

I'm currently receiving Carbon dates like: **2021-03-17 17:14:42.01811**, and I would like to not consider hours, minutes and seconds, converting it to the start of the day.

This value is not meant to be formatted to a string because in the code it is used for comparison against other dates.

I managed to make a solution, but it doesn't seem to be the most valid one,  **I'm using `now()` function as an example**.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Is there a more correct way to do this operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `hour`, `minute` and `second` setters of Carbon.

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
$dt->hour = 0;
$dt->minute = 0;
$dt->second = 0;
```

[See docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-setters)

Or the fluent setters:

```
$dt = Carbon::now()
    ->hour(0)
    ->minute(0)
    ->second(0);
```

Or use fluent setter `setTime($hour, $minute, $second = 0, $microseconds = 0)` which also sets the microsecond to zero:

```
$dt = Carbon::now()->setTime(0, 0)
```

[See docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-settersfluent)

Comment: See the other answers with `Carbon::today()` or `->startOfDay()`

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for

```
    Carbon::today()
```

Answer (score 2):

> converting it to the start of the day.

```
Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
```

Try it out: https://try-carbon-lib.herokuapp.com/?input=echo%20Carbon%3A%3Anow()-%3EstartOfDay()%3B

Answer (score 0):

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Simply use this

```
    $dt = Carbon::now();
    echo $dt->toDateString();
```